# Can I use captureScreenshotOnFailure to capture an error not only the failure in selenium RC?

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, phpunit, selenium-rc

I'm trying to capture the screen whenever something goes wrong, either an error or failure

Comment: Selenium has captureEntirePageScreenshot and captureScreenshot. Is captureScreenshotOnFailure which you have mentioned in the question, part of something else?

Comment: Assuming your requirement is to capture the screenshot whenever a test fails, you need to have the logic to intercept the failures. Are you using testNG or anything similar to intercept the failure?

Comment: Its a selenium function also, and i'm using PHPunit as i'm testing PHP projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selenium.captureScreenshot()` create a util method which you can call whenever you want to capture the screen shot. However if you are using Testng then you can refer http://satishjohn.wordpress.com/2012/06/04/selenium-testng-error-screenshot-listene/ but this is for failedtest passedtest skipped test. however you can put the capturescreen shot as a helper method in you utilities and call it under the testng method.